# TagOverflow – interactive exploration of Stack Exchange tags

Tags: discussion, tags

(Taken from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248579/tagoverflow-interactive-exploration-of-stack-exchange-tags) and adapted to German Language Stack Exchange)

[image: TagOverflow]

Nodes represent the most popular tags. The area is proportional to the number of questions.

Edges represent relation between tags. The width is related to the number of questions with both tags. The shade is related to how often they occur compared to what is expected merely by random chance.

Link: http://stared.github.io/tagoverflow/?site=german&size=32